# Как написать программу так чтобы она читала букву и цифру?

Tags: python

Задача выглядеть так, в одну строчку написано имя человека и его возраст, и нужно написать так чтобы программу написал его возраст уже в следующем году. К примеру Егору 16 лет, и чтобы программа написала Егору 17 лет. По факту задача легкая но я хз как её писать. Моя попытка:

```
a,b = input(),int(input())
c = b + 1
print(a,c)
```

Comment: *в одну строчку написано имя человека и его возраст* так у 2 `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в одну строчку - это так что ли?
ту и ввод и вывод одной строкой

```
print(*[i[1] if i[0] == 0 else (int(i[1]) + 1) for i in enumerate(input().split())])
```

или имеется в виду ввести данные одной строкой?

```
a,b = input().split()
c = int(b) + 1
print(a,c)
```

Comment: Спасибо Zhihar, ты мне помог уже второй раз спасибо еще раз. Ну по факту второй вид решения более подходить для меня, потому что он простой и понятный. Спасибо еще раз!